# using value of variable and string to fetch from terraform data source

Tags: variables, terraform, datasource, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to fetch some certficates from hashicorp vault using tf data source

This is how cert path looks like in vault

```
serverA:
  dev-cert: <base64 encoded cert>
  qa-cert: <base64 encoded cert>
  test-cert: <base64 encoded cert>
```

This cert is used in other  resource block which works fine as shown below

```
resource <somegcpresource> <xyz>
{
   certificate = base64decode(data.vault_generic_secret.server_cryptoobjects.data["dev-cert"])
}
```

1. Can I use a custom env variable  to fetch value of certificate like;

   `certificate = base64decode(data.vault_generic_secret.server_cryptoobjects.data["var.env-cert"])`
2. or a local var to reference the key name from vault datasource like;

   `certificate = base64decode(data.vault_generic_secret.server_cryptoobjects.data[local.certname])`

Comment: Did you try? Do you have any code to show with any errors that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `data.vault_generic_secret.server_cryptoobjects.data` is an object so you can access its values with their corresponding keys. If you declare a variable `env-cert`:

```
variable "env-cert" {
  type    = string
  default = "dev-cert"
}
```

then you can use it as the key:

```
certificate = base64decode(data.vault_generic_secret.server_cryptoobjects.data["var.env-cert"])
```

Yes you can also use a local as the key:

```
locals {
  certname = "dev-cert"
}

certificate = base64decode(data.vault_generic_secret.server_cryptoobjects.data[local.certname])
```

I would also suggest looking at the Vault PKI secrets engine for your overall use case if you have not already, since this example in the question is using the KV2 secrets engine.

Comment: Thanks certificate = base64decode(data.vault_generic_secret.server_cryptoobjects.data["var.env-cert"]) works.